# Azure Spatial Anchors

Tags: android, ios, azure, unity-game-engine

Would it be beneficial to use Azure Spatial Anchors in Unity 3d for an indoor and outdoor augmented reality experience to be deployed on both ios and android?

Comment: [oafolabi-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15408613) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68643713) saying "@skynard, are you still having a problem with the setup? Please create a new issue at the ASA samples repository, and we can investigate the problem further: [https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/issues)."

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is a reasonable scenario for [Azure Spatial Anchors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/overview). By developing your app with ASA + Unity, you'll be able to deploy to iOS, Android, and HoloLens. If you'd like some additional guidelines on the best practices for your experience, take a look at [this concept page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/concepts/guidelines-effective-anchor-experiences).

Comment: I would need to build the Unity project on a windows workstation correct?  Would I need also to initiate the anchors via gps for outdoors or bluetooth beacons for indoors?

Comment: The [quickstart guides] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/unity-overview) contain the workstation prerequisites. Depending on the platform, you'll either use Unity for Windows or Unity for MacOS. Leveraging GPS and other external sensors are optional but [recommended for certain scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spatial-anchors/concepts/coarse-reloc).

Comment: I had no luck with mrtk and spatial anchors on a mac.  Couldn't add the anchor module script in the inspector window for parent anchor.    I was told I needed to use windows platform.  Is that correct?

Comment: @skynard, if you are still having issues with the MRTK tutorial, please file an issue at the bottom of the tutorial page by selecting the "This page" button. You do not need MRTK to use ASA. If you have an ASA-specific question, please file an issue in our GitHub samples repo. Thanks!